# May I ask why my Nestjs route cannot be loaded correctly?

Tags: nestjs

it like `RouterModule.register` not work

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AdminModule } from './app/admin/admin.module';
import { ShopModule } from './app/shop/shop.module';

@Module({
  imports: [RouterModule.register([{
    path: 'admin',
    module: AdminModule
  }, {
    path: 'shop',
    module: ShopModule
  }])],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class HttpModule { }
```

no any route load :(

if I change the HttpModule like this

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AdminModule } from './app/admin/admin.module';
import { ShopModule } from './app/shop/shop.module';

@Module({
  imports: [AdminModule,ShopModule],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class HttpModule { }
```

it work , but no route prefix :(

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you are not importing the modules. Even if you use router module you have to import those modules too.

```js
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { RouterModule } from "@nestjs/core";
import { AdminModule } from "./app/admin/admin.module";
import { ShopModule } from "./app/shop/shop.module";

@Module({
  imports: [
    AdminModule, // here is the difference
    ShopModule, // here is the difference
    RouterModule.register([
      {
        path: "admin",
        module: AdminModule,
      },
      {
        path: "shop",
        module: ShopModule,
      },
    ]),
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class HttpModule {}
```